# java program to find prime factors of a number

Tags: java

```
public class PrimeFactor {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number:");
    int num=input.nextInt();
    int factors;
    for(int i=1;i<num;i++)
    {
        factors=num%i;
        if(factors==0 && isPrime(factors))
        System.out.println(i+"");
    }
    input.close();
}
public static boolean isPrime(int n)
{
    boolean prime=true;
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            prime=false;
            break;
        }

    }
    return prime;
}

}
```

I have written this code to find the prime factors of a number. The logic I have applied seems fine to me but the output is coming wrong.

Comment: What should the output be? What is it actually? What has your debugging revealed? Why did you write the logic this way? What does it accomplish? Why do you think so?

Comment: The output should be prime factors but it is showing all the factors except 1 and itself. There is no reason to why i wrote the logic this way, it just the first thing that came to my mind. @SotiriosDelimanolis

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=1;i<num;i++)
    {
        factors=num%i;
        if(factors==0 && isPrime(factors))
        System.out.println(i+"");
    }
    input.close();
```

`factors` is the remainder of `num / i`. So if `factors` returns `0`, then you are passing `0` to your method `isPrime()`, which makes no sense. I think you might want to be passing `i` to `isPrime`, not `factors`.

So your loop should be the same thing, but with a different parameter passed to the `isPrime()` function.

```
for(int i=1;i<num;i++)
    {
        factors=num%i;
        if(factors==0 && isPrime(i))
        System.out.println(i+"");
    }
    input.close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have made such a silly mistake. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

DanGordon is correct in saying you should pass `i` instead of `factors` to `isPrime()`. That prevents composite numbers from being outputted, but that still doesn't fix the issue that the inputted number won't be displayed even if it is prime. The problem there lies with your `for` loop. `i<num` tells the program to iterate through the `for` loop only as long as `i` is less than the number entered, so, once `i` is equal to the `num`, it breaks out of the loop. If you change `i<num` to `i<=num`, it will ensure the loop runs when `i` is equal to the entered number as well, and therefore it should display the number entered if that number is prime.